# Is a chi square test appropriate?

Tags: chi-squared-test, spatial, paired-data, independence

I have a dataset which consists of fish density/biomass from two sampling periods (1 and 2) in two locations (A and B). In sampling period 1 locations A and B are both clear, while in sampling period 2 A is clear but B is experiencing very high turbidity. I want to assess whether the increased turbidity has caused a change in how the fish are using the habitat-- i.e. if they are preferentially choosing the clear "A" location at sampling period 2, compared to sampling period 1.

I was thinking I could assess this with a chi-square test, but my measures of biomass and density are continuous, not discrete-- would rounding up to the nearest whole number be valid?/Any other suggestions on how to analyze this? I don't think an ANOVA will work because I really only have one measure of density/biomass per group/time.

*** EDIT ***

I actually have 100's of measures of density and biomass in each sampling of the 4 sampling areas/periods-- density and biomass were obtained using a sonar-like device that pings the fish every minute or so. But these measures obviously won't be independent of each other, so I was planning on just averaging across the sampling period.

Comment: No.  Your measurements are not counts and rounding to integers won't make them counts. After all, you could change your units of measurement and get quite different integers after rounding.  It sounds as if you have no information about variability in any case.

Comment: It sounds as if you have 4 data points, A1, A2, B1 and B2, and you want to see if there is a change between B1 and B2 using A1 and A2 as controls.  Without knowing more about the fluctuations (eg the points follow a gaussian distribution), I think it is hard to say much.  Otherwise, you could build a model and do a likelihood ratio test.

Comment: Can you make an assumption as to the typical fish mass in order to obtain the number of fish, and from there use Poisson statistics, or Gaussian if the numbers are high enough?

Comment: You can't somehow "back-engineer" your measurements to estimate a count of fish, can you? The theory behind the chi squared test is valid for counts, not for continuous measurments, as was already stated. That said, even if you had counts, it'd be dubious to assume that the fish are independent of each other, which would also be required by the chi-squared test.

Comment: @NickCox Actually, I have a little bit of variability information-- the fish data was collected via a sonar-like device which pinged the fish and calculated the number and biomass of them at that instance in time. It did this every second or so in each sampling area for about 100 seconds (so 400 measurements total). Because these samples weren't going to be independent of each other I was planning on just averaging across each sampling area/period, but maybe there's a way to use those data? Could I use that data to estimate the number of fish in each area and then do a Chi square test on that?

Comment: Can you take measurements that are more time apart from each other, so that independence looks more realistic?

Comment: @Lewian To clarify I do actually have measures of the number of fish per acre (density), and biomass. The reason that the result comes out as continuous is because I have 100 measures of density and biomass per sampling period/time which I average to obtain an overall density measure (because the 100 density measurements within the same sampling period/time won't be independent of each other).

Comment: But you wouldn't think it is reasonable to assume the individual fish independent of each other, would you?

Comment: @Lewian The sampling was in response to a once in 100-year rainfall event which led to increased turbidity. It would be impossible to recreate the unique site conditions for the"treatment" sampling period.

Comment: It's not clear you can make these independent. They sound like pseudoreplications to me.  I think you have 4 data points. You can simply report the four numbers as descriptive.

Comment: S. Thompson describes how to analyze such samples in his book *Sampling.* The later chapters focus on methods to sample ecological systems, such as transect sampling. The idea is that you need to estimate the chances of detecting any individual and any pair of individuals in the population (based, perhaps, on the properties of your sonar); and then you can use those chances in a Hansen-Hurwitz like estimator.

Comment: @Lewian I assume the individual fish to be independent of each other-- but I can't say with any confidence that the 19th ping taken within a given sampling period/area is going to have completely different individuals than the 20th ping.

Comment: @Dugan, within each of the 4 categories, what causes the fluctuations?  If it is not the number of fish, can it be the instrument used to make measurements?

Comment: @MisterMak Imagine there is a camera on the bottom of the boat. The camera takes a picture of all of the fish which are directly under the boat every minute. The boat weaves back and forth over the sampling area and takes 100 pictures in total. There is variation in the number of fish in each picture, but no way to say with any confidence how many of those fish are unique individuals. This is why I was planning on averaging across all of the fish "photos" because the measurements won't be independent from each other.

Comment: whuber's reference is probably better, but one thing that could be done is you could run an exemplary chi squared test on some fish numbers that make some sense at some point in time. If this gives you a p-value of about zero (really far lower than any reasonable cutoff for significance) you could state that the evidence looks very clear and strong for a change despite the specific test just giving an example calculation rather than being precise for your problem. (Of course still assuming that individual fish are independent.)

Comment: For each of the measurements A1, A2, B1 and B2, if you take the mean and standard deviation, would that overestimate the fluctuations?  If so, and you do a likelihood ratio test, could you still put a constraint on the p-value?

Comment: @MisterMak I think it'd be more likely underestimate the fluctuations since the individuals in ping #20 could be recounted in ping #21.

Comment: Is there maybe some way to develop a measure of how independent the samples are from each other? like if I assume that fish follow a random walk type movement pattern then samples that are collected farther away from one another both temporally and spatially should be more independent? Could this then be used to do some sort of likelihood ratio test?

Comment: @whuber maybe I'm misunderstanding it but I just read up on  Hansen-Hurwitz like estimators-- my understanding is that this is a way to estimate total population size when you have samples collected from clusters of different sizes. Like estimating the total number of trees on a set of islands when you assess the number of trees on a subset of the islands and then correct for island size. So I'm not sure how it would apply here.

Comment: If you are not trying to estimate the size of some kind of fish population, then what are you trying to do?

Comment: @whuber I'm trying to determine whether the fish are preferentially choosing the clear sampling area versus the non-turbid sampling area. I can see how estimating population size would get me that (I could enter the population size estimate in the chi-square analysis), but I don't see how a Hansen-Hurwitz like estimator would work in this situation. The issue is not that my samples are from different sized clusters, it's that they're not spatially/temporally independent of each other.

Comment: I would think coefficient estimates from a linear model would be sufficient if you use the individual samples? 

Roughly $y = \beta_0 + \beta_{loc} x_{loc} + \beta_{turbid} x_{turbid} + \epsilon$. $\epsilon \sim N(0, \sigma)$ or similar with centered/standardized $y_i$. (Maybe with interaction?) 

If you dummy-coded $x_{turbid}$, then $\beta_{turbid}$ would reflect the expected deviation from baseline associated with turbid conditions.

You can then compute related p-values / confidence intervals if you want, or use the model for ANOVA, etc.

Comment: @Gianni Thanks for the suggestion! I've just been reading up on spatial regression models. I don't know much about them so I'm a little unsure on the formula you've provided. Is this a spatial error model, a spatial lag model a SLX spatially lagged X model or a global spatial model? Which do you suggest and why? Do you have a recommended program for running this? I have been reading about GeoDa and the R package spdep.

Comment: I had something simpler in mind. I understand your locations as categorical: you're either in location A or B. Likewise for observation periods. Likewise for turbidity. So you can treat these as binary indicator variables in a regression model.

Even though your samples within a group are not IID, they are IID wrt samples within other groups. The coefficient for turbidity is an expected deflection between groups, not samples. So I think you shouldn't need a structured noise model, unless there are other within-group differences you're interested in.

Comment: For software: I'm not that familiar with the R ecosystem. I would approach this with `statsmodels` in Python as the simplest choice. (Usually I'd put a prior on it and actually work in `PyMC3` or `numpyro`, but that might be overkill for your purposes, unless there's a lot of additional complexity that's of practical interest to you.)

Answer (score 1):

Would this work (posting as an answer because it's not really a comment)?

I have 100 samples in each of the four sampling groups (A1, A2, B1, and B2). The samples collected within A1 are not independent from each other, but they are independent from the samples collected in A2, B1 and B2.

Therefore, could I take a random sample in sampling group A1, another random sample in sampling group A2, B1 and B2 and perform a Chi-square test on these 4 numbers. Obtain the Chi-square test statistic and then repeat this procedure 10,000 times to obtain an average Chi-square value with a standard error, and then get a p Value from that?

Comment: I think it depends on what statistical rigour you want.  You could probably obtain a result that convinces people (and even referees) if the effect exists (or doesn't), though you should explain clearly what you are doing.  Also, it is often useful to run simulations (ie generate mock data sets A1, A2, B1 and B2 and push them through your analysis pipeline) ahead of time to see if things behave as expected.

Comment: If observations in A1 are not independent of each other, randomly sampled elements from A1 are not independent either. So no, random sampling from your data doesn't help.

Comment: @Lewian even if I’m only using one “photo” per group? i.e. one photo of fish numbers from each of groups A1, A2, B1, B2, is hen calculate the chi square, then repeat?

Comment: Can you show the distribution of counts in A1 for instance, to confirm whether or not if follows a Poisson distribution?

Comment: @Dugan: As I wrote before as a comment to the original question, if you use one number per group a chi squared test can be, let's say, "well motivated", and if that gives you an "about zero" p-value, I'd be fine with the conclusion that something's going on there. However if you repeat this with different photos, you don't add independent information, so I don't see this getting you much further.